# Spring-boot-application with Hive-connection doesn't start embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, hive, spring-data

I use Spring-Boot and want to connect it to Hive by spring-data-hadoop 2.3.0.M1-hdp23. The problem is that my application doesn't start if I add hive-jdbc to my pom.xml. The **errorlog** (partly) is:

```
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)
     2015-08-11 14:46:58.582  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] com.myApp.Application             : Starting Application on m with PID 3528 (/home/user/workspace/myApp/target/classes started by user in /home/user/workspace/myApp)
     2015-08-11 14:46:58.783  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5c01b2f: startup date [Tue Aug 11 14:46:58 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
     2015-08-11 14:47:02.993  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
     2015-08-11 14:47:03.829  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65dc2a7d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
     2015-08-11 14:47:03.933  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
     2015-08-11 14:47:03.991  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
     2015-08-11 14:47:04.015  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
     2015-08-11 14:47:05.661  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
     2015-08-11 14:47:06.563  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
     2015-08-11 14:47:06.566  INFO 3528 --- [lication.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
     2015-08-11 14:47:07.336  INFO 3528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
     2015-08-11 14:47:07.339  INFO 3528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8567 ms
     2015-08-11 14:47:10.608  INFO 3528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4a329af, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@730530af, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@777febdc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@29ef5cb1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@27cac72b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@17efd160, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@711567b0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@f16564d, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@221bfb42, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4146c6af, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@710a1397]
     2015-08-11 14:47:10.802  INFO 3528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
     2015-08-11 14:47:10.829 ERROR 3528 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 common frames omitted
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:189)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 common frames omitted

     [...]

     org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.myApp.Application.main(Application.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 13 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:337)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:88)
... 18 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 20 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 22 common frames omitted
     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 24 common frames omitted

     [...]

     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project myApp: An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start
```

My **pom.xml** looks (partly) like:

```
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

         <parent>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
         </parent>

         <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>    
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>   
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
             </dependency>

            <!-- Hive Dependencies -->
                    <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-boot</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.M1-hdp23</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

I have defined two data sources to use Hive and MySQL together, one as ***@Primary*** - but this is not a/the problem. My **Application.java** is:

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
    @ComponentScan("com.myApp")
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Interesting is: If I delete the ***hive-jdbc dependency*** out of my **pom.xml** the application starts and I can do everything else, like accessing my MySQL-connection and access all classes. Only if I want to access hive I got a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**. For sure, he can't find it because the dependency is missing, but it shows that this dependency makes trouble. I tried other versions, without success. If I remove the ***exclusion-tag*** I got an other error:

```
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping.setDefault(Z)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.myApp.Application.main(Application.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping.setDefault(Z)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:289)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureWebAppContext(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:236)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Hope anyone has an idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: it works well for my spring boot+hibernate application, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same situation.

In my case, it was a conflict on the servlet-api.

I added this exclusion in my pom.xml file :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This dependency works for me.
**Note**: Do not use hive-jdbc version 3.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
      <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using gradle:

```
implementation('org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate'
}
```